# Heroku doesn't seem to install module

Tags: python, heroku

My app keeps crashing instantly and following the Heroku logs I find this:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_socketio'`,
but my requirements.txt does say:
`Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1`.

How do I get Heroku to install it?

My python import statement reads: `from flask_socketio import SocketIO` if that matters.

Comment: Are you entirely sure you've deployed a version that contains that line? Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, or just a `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes, pipfile reads: `[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
flask = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
`

Comment: ahh got it! I read up on pipfile vs requirements.txt for heroku.

Comment: Got it. If you have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, Heroku installs dependencies from _those_ files using Pipenv and completely ignores `requirements.txt`.